# C# PUSH(int data), pop() and getmin() value from the stack without using collections

Tags: c#

I want to retrieve the minimum value that is entered (through push(int)) in the stack.

Here is my sample code so far written for `Push` and `Pop` but I failed to get the minimum value

```
class Program
{

    private int StackSize;

    public int StackSizeSet
    {
        get { return StackSize; }
        set { StackSize = value; }
    }

    public int top;
    Object[] item;

    public Program()
    {

        StackSizeSet = 10;
        item = new Object[StackSizeSet];
        top = -1;
    }

    public void isMinimum()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i <StackSizeSet; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mianimum value is" + item[top]);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public bool isEmpty()
    {

        if (top == -1) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void Push(int value)
    {

        if (top == (StackSize - 1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stack is full!");
        }
        else
        {
            item[++top] = value;
            Console.WriteLine("Item pushed successfully!");
            Console.WriteLine(item[top]);
        }
    }

    public object Pop()
    {

        if (isEmpty())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stack is empty!");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return "No elements";
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Items popped successfully");
            return item[top--];
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Program p = new Program();
        p.Push(10);
        p.Pop();
        p.isMinimum();
        //Console.WriteLine(p);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the sample code?

Comment: [Don't forget to **take the SO Tour** it will guide you on how to best use SO](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: Mahmood attached the sample code

Comment: Why are you using `Object[]` when you're dealing with `int`?  Wouldn't `int[]` be more appropriate?

Comment: yes that can be changed to int[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your `Minimum` method does it iterate through the items in the stack.  You can use LINQ to get the minimum value quite easily, but if you want to do it without collections then you can do it the long way - go through the stack and keep storing the lowest value; once you've gone through the stack you'll have your answer.

Assuming you're using `int[]` instead of `Object[]` (so we don't have to deal with casts):

```
int minValue = item[0];

for (int i = 1; i <StackSizeSet; i++)
{

    if (minValue > item[i])
    {
        minValue = item[i];
    }        
}
```

Basically, the above code will set the minimum value equal to the first element in the array (the oldest element in the stack).

Then it will loop through the remaining elements, comparing the current element to the current mimimum value - if the current element is lower, then minimum value is updated to the current value.

Once the loop is done, you'll have the minimum value for your stack.

Comment: Thanks Tim.I used int[] instead of Object[]

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the items themselves, you should store the minima of a sub stack. So you will have:

```
int[] items;
int[] minima; //initialize in constructor
```

On `Push` you can add the minimum to the stack:

```
public void Push(int value)
{
    if (top == (StackSize - 1))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stack is full!");
    }
    else
    {          
        item[++top] = value;
        if(top == 0)
            minima[top] = value;
        else
            minima[top] = Math.Min(value, minima[top - 1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Item pushed successfully!");
        Console.WriteLine(item[top]);
    }
}
```

In order to calculate the minimum you only have to look at the top most element on the minima stack, which will give you `O(1)` time complexity instead of `O(n)`.

Here is an example (stack from bottom to top):

```
items  minima
-------------
  1    1
  7    2
  5    2
  2    2
  3    3
```

Comment: +1 That's actually a more elegant solution than what I had.